# Type Safety given strings of property names

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have created an operator "pluck" that maps over an object and returns values whose property names match the list of strings provided to pluck:

```
const pluck = (...args: string[]) => map(val => args.reduce((props, propName) => {
  props[propName] = val[propName];
  return props;
}, {}));

pluck('name', 'id', 'login');
```

Is there any way to implement type safety to ensure that the type that gets passed to the `pluck` operation? I've tried using generics:

```
const pluck = <T>(...args: string[]) => map<T>((val: T) => args.reduce((props, propName) => {
  props[propName] = val[propName];
  return props;
}, {}));
```

but this doesn't work possibly because of the array access syntax. However, `val.prop` doesn't work because the property doesn't exist on type `T`.

This implementation works on arrays:

```
const pluck = (arr, ...args) => arr.map(val => args.reduce((props, propName) => {
  props[propName] = val[propName];
  return props;
}, {}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what `map` in your first `pluck` example does, but typed version for arrays looks like

```
const pluck = <T, E extends keyof T>(arr: T[], ...args: E[]) => arr.map((val: T) => args.reduce((props, propName) => {
  props[propName] = val[propName];
  return props;
}, {} as {[e in E]: T[e]}));

interface Z {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    name: string;
    id: string;
    login: string;
}

let z: Z[] = [];

let p = pluck(z, 'name', 'id', 'login'); 
// p's type is inferred as  { name: string; id: string; login: string; }[]
```

The trick is to introduce another generic parameter E, restricted to a subset of keys of `T`. Also, type assertion is necessary to cast empty object to the eventual `props` return type. Then, `props[propName]` can be typechecked - `props` has mapped type `{[e in E]: T[e]}`, and `propName` has `E` as its type.

**UPDATE**

For RxJX, the best typing I could come up with for completely generic `pluck` operator is this. It's not good because it infers property types as `any`, but at least it checks property names:

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/let";


import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';

import {map, filter} from "rxjs/operators";
import {OperatorFunction} from "rxjs/interfaces";


const source = Observable.from([
  { name: 'Joe', age: 30, id: 123, login: 'joe1' },
  { name: 'Frank', age: 20, id: 456, login: 'frank1956' },
  { name: 'Ryan', age: 50, id: 2, login: 'z' }
]);


const pluck = <E extends string, T extends {[e in E]: T[e]}>(...args: E[]): OperatorFunction<T, {[e in E]: T[e]}> => map((val: T) => args.reduce((props, propName) => {
  props[propName] = val[propName];
  return props;
}, {} as {[e in E]: T[e]}));


const p = pluck('name', 'id', 'login');



const d = source.let(p); // Observable<{ name: any; id: any; login: any; }>
```

You can add another level of functions and specify input type explicitly as type parameter for a function that returns actual `pluck`,  however:

```
type PluckOperatorType<T> = <E extends keyof T>(...args: E[]) => OperatorFunction<T, {[e in E]: T[e]}>;

const pluck = <T>(): PluckOperatorType<T> => <E extends keyof T>(...args: E[]) => map((val: T) => args.reduce((props, propName) => {
  props[propName] = val[propName];
  return props;
}, {} as {[e in E]: T[e]}));

interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    id: number;
    login: string;
}

const p = pluck<Person>()('name', 'id', 'login');

const d = source.let(p); // Observable<{ name: string; id: number; login: string; }>
```

Comment: `map` in the first example is the RxJS map operator

Comment: Actually this does work for RxJS. It wasn't working properly for my use case due to a somewhat unrelated bug in another library I'm using.

Comment: Actually there was a bug in my answer - mapped type should be `{[e in E]: T[e]}`, not {[e in E]: T[E]}.  (the last `E` should be `e`). Also I was trying to find a solution for RxJS, I updated the answer.

Comment: This actually doesn't seem to make a difference... do you have an example of where using `T[M]` is not type safe where `T[e]` is?

Comment: I can't come up with the example right now, but in that code, the difference is that T[M] is a union type of all property types of properties with names in M, T[e] is a single property type.

Comment: Actually i can see an error... `pluck('name', 'x'), filter(({ name, x }) => x === name)` is not an error with `T[M]` due to the union type.